# How to use Solana Wallet Key to sign TX for ArweaveJS

Tags: typescript, solana, metaplex

Is there any way to use a Solana wallet keypair and load it into the JWKInterface as per the `node_modules/arweave/node/lib/wallet.d.ts` and then create an Arweave TX with `await arweave.createTransaction({ data }, jwk);`?

Given metaplex uses an API call for their Arweave uploader and it's a hidden piece of code would be nice to crack this in native JS/TS if it's possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you referring to https://github.com/ArweaveTeam/arweave-js ?

That requires a arweave and not a solana wallet. You can use e.g. arkb for the upload

If you want to build something yourself in JS have a look at the cookbook. https://solanacookbook.com/references/nfts.html#upload-to-arweave

Comment: I'm assuming Metaplex maintain two wallets at their endpoint that allow the user to pay in SOL and then they execute the Arwevae TX from the Arweave wallet. Might have to look at doing something similar...